# Can we accept an answer more than 1 time? The reputation tab tooltip seems to think so

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, tooltips, activity

In the [reputation tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=reputation), when hovering on the accepted answer, I can see the tooltip as "answer was accepted 1 time". It seems to imply that the answer can be accepted multiple times.

Wouldn't it be enough for the tooltip to say "answer was accepted", to avoid any confusion?

> [image: Rep tab]

Comment: Actually, since the tooltip is shown only on single vote records, the "1 time" can be removed from *all* tooltips.

Comment: In theory the answer could have been accepted/ unaccepted / accepted multiple times on the same day, not sure if that rolls-up in one event, anywhere, ever.

Comment: Including how many times it was accepted doesn't seem terribly relevant in terms of being an instructive tooltip. It's just confusing and should probably be dropped and the tooltip clarified.

Comment: @Glorfindel by "all tooltips", I don't think so, unless I misinterpret your comment exclusively for the "accept vote". For upvotes/downvotes, at least on the "Time" tab, [multiple votes are collected into 1 "up/downvote" event if the time is similar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUPcN.png).

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. I think I wrote that while looking at the Post tab; I never use the Time tab.

Comment: Thank god it isn't *accepted 1 time**s***. :)

Comment: @iBugsaysReinstateMonica I've had 1 flags remaining before, so either they corrected the plural for that but not for flagging or it's been "hard-coded" to only have 1 there.  I'm tempted to inspect the source code to find out more...